# Pandas Most Recent "N" Non NA values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
2019-03-13 11:30:00+08:00       NaN       NaN  0.001143
2019-03-13 15:00:00+08:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-03-14 01:00:00+08:00  0.003653       NaN       NaN
2019-03-14 10:15:00+08:00       NaN -0.002743       NaN
2019-03-14 11:30:00+08:00       NaN       NaN  0.000229
2019-03-14 15:00:00+08:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-03-15 01:00:00+08:00 -0.000229       NaN       NaN
2019-03-15 10:15:00+08:00       NaN  0.003211       NaN
2019-03-15 11:30:00+08:00       NaN       NaN -0.006192
2019-03-15 15:00:00+08:00       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Is there a way to get the most recent N=2 values for each column without looping? ie, skipping all the `NaN`. There exist a `last_valid_index()`, but that only gets the last value. It would be nice to get a reindex dataframe abset of the datetime so they are aligned. Is this possible?

Expected Output:

```
   1  0.003653  -0.002743     0.000229
   2  -0.000229  0.003211    -0.006192
```

Comment: please show your expected output

Answer (score 3):

IIUC

```
df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.notnull)).iloc[-2:]
                   1         2         3
2019-03-15  0.003653 -0.002743  0.000229
2019-03-15 -0.000229  0.003211 -0.006192
```

Comment: Does this also sort by time? as it was mentioned that we want to retrieve the "most recent" ones

Comment: @MohammadZeineldeen I am assuming his index already well ordered, if not just df=df.sort_index()

Comment: As long as the last row (bottom) is the most recent value for that column, should be good. Think of it like data coming in asynchronously, don't care much relative order just the most recent observations.